# QGIS - selecting 3D Polygons

Tags: qgis, 3d, select

I have downloaded a 3D polygon shapefile of buildings. I would like to be able to select some of the objects to create a new shapefile for doing 3D rendering but I cannot seem to be able to select any of the objects unless they don't have elevation. Is there some way that you have to select the polygons when they have height?

Answer (score 2):

Since you say they have height I am assuming you have a field in your attribute table for Height or Z-Value.

You would use the select by expression and assuming your Height Field is named ZVALUE, it would look like this

"ZVALUE" > 0

This will select only polygons with a height above 0 (or all polygons with a height value)

If you want to export out your selection you can do that as well, by exporting only the selected features.

Here are some tutorials and guides, the first one is excellent and very in depth

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_attributes.html

http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html

http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/query.php